# Supporting multiple versions of iOS in a static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, ios8, ios-frameworks

We maintain a number of static libraries targeting iOS 7, as part of the upcoming release of iOS 8 it would be good to be able to support some of the new features in things like Core Data and Core Location.

Is the only the option to produce two versions of the library, one targeting iOS 7 and one targeting iOS 8, or is there a way to support both in the same library.

It would be good to get to a point where if the app using the library is targeting iOS 8 then extra features become available, and if your targeting iOS 7 then you just get the current features..

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.  I haven't used it inside a library but I can't think why it wouldn't work there:

```
SEL registerUserNotificationSettings = NSSelectorFromString(@"registerUserNotificationSettings:");

// iOS 8 requires explicit permission from the user for local notifications
if ([application respondsToSelector:registerUserNotificationSettings]) {

    //Extra hack for the bit settings since we're building with a SDK that doesn't have the symbols
    #define REQUIRED_SETTINGS 7

    Class settingsClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIUserNotificationSettings");
    if (settingsClass) {
        id settings = objc_msgSend(settingsClass, @selector(settingsForTypes:categories:), REQUIRED_SETTINGS, nil);
        objc_msgSend(application, registerUserNotificationSettings, settings);
    }
}
```

This is implemented inside a code section that assumes it's being built with the iOS 7 SDK.  The `respondsToSelector:` is essentially an iOS 8+ runtime check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you can do this automatically, since at link time, you have no idea what hardware the image will run on.

You could use a facade pattern.  When you realise that a particular method could be implemented differently depending on iOS, create your two versions and let the facade forward the method to the appropriate version.

The cleanest way to do this is with the Objective C runtime methods.  You need to get the objective c runtime guide from Apple.  The stuff you want to look at is method swizzling e.g. setImplementation.  Each time you instantiate a interface object, you can run through the os version dependent methods and set the appropriate implementations.